# Can I get a Blue Card visa from Germany if I have a probation for cannabis consumption?

Tags: germany, blue-card

Im a software developer from Turkey. I was caught using cannabis and sentenced to 1 year probation (without court) which consists of 3 one-on-one, 10 group sessions and a urine test which I completed all. I have an employment contract with a company in Germany and will apply for a Blue card visa. The probation is not listed in my criminal record, but is asked in the visa application form.

Can I get rejected because of the probation, or is there anything I need to do while applying?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, your application can get rejected for pretty much *anything*.
Publicly stating Russia’s incursion of February 24, 2022, into Ukraine was good could be a just cause to reject someone’s application.

**No**, I *don’t expect* a DUI, cannabis consumption or any other one-time misdemeanors to be a reason to reject your application, *especially* since you *intend to pay taxes*.

[Meanwhile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BYZzoWg1sD8&t=305), the current federal administration has the declared intention to legalize recreational cannabis use, but policymakers haven’t approved a law yet.
If there was a law, it would be even less of a concern, I think.

Comment: I see. Should I state smt that's not in my criminal record in visa application? Wdyt about that?

Comment: It’s your call. Omitting information is a _very easy_ reason for expulsion, though. On the other hand the omitted information must have potentially made a difference to your visa approval. Omitting “as a 6-year-old boy I shoplifted a candy bar” is really no problem. Omitting “I used to work for the MİT” could be a problem. It’s hard to tell where to put your case. I wouldn’t worry so much if recreational cannabis use became legal in the meantime, because, if you were found guilty of adultery in a sharia-governed nation, the FRG would not care about that (as it’s not illegal in the FRG).